# Skip symlinks while recursively listing files with Hadoop's FileSystem

Tags: java, hadoop, symlink

I'm using Hadoop's `FileSystem` (`org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`) to recursively list all the files under a directory:

```
FileSystem.listFiles(new Path("file:/my/path"), true)
```

However, I have a recursive symlink `/my/path/symlink -> /my/path`, and `listFiles` returns a huge list of paths like

```
/my/path/symlink
/my/path/symlink/symlink
/my/path/symlink/symlink/symlink
/my/path/symlink/symlink/symlink/symlink
/my/path/symlink/symlink/symlink/symlink/symlink
...
```

Is there a flag, or a configuration parameter to prevent this?

I need to use `FileSystem` because I'm using both `hdfs:/` and `file:/` paths.

Answer (score 1):

Once I had the need to just list directories recursively under a path and I wrote my own listDirectories function based on the code for listFiles in FileSystem.java.

If you look at the code, it is very simple, just you should avoid recurring on a FileStatus if it is a symlink. But then the caveat is that you will not get paths which include a parent symlink.

you should change this function:

```
private void handleFileStat(LocatedFileStatus stat) throws IOException {
    if (stat.isFile()) { // file
      curFile = stat;
    } else if (recursive) { // directory
      itors.push(curItor);
      curItor = listLocatedStatus(stat.getPath());
    }
  }
```

to something like:

```
private void handleFileStat(LocatedFileStatus stat) throws IOException {
    if (stat.isFile()) { // file
      curFile = stat;
    } else if (recursive && !stat.isSymlink()) { // directory and not symlink
      itors.push(curItor);
      curItor = listLocatedStatus(stat.getPath());
    }
  }
```